# Accessing azure custom field using OData query

Tags: azure, azure-devops, odata

I have created a Custom field in one of our azure DevOps projects.
Field `Reference Name: Custom.TestingType`. [image]
Now I want to access this field with an Odata query,

```
https://analytics.dev.azure.com/companyName-ProjectName/myProjectName/_odata/v4.0-preview/WorkItemSnapshot?  
$apply=filter(WorkItemType eq 'Test Case')
/groupby(
    (WorkItemId, Title, WorkItemType, State, Reason, Custom_Module, Iteration/IterationPath, ChangedDate, Custom_TestingType) 
)
```

Using above code I get an error.
[image]

Also custom field is not available in the metadata.
We accessing azure data schema metadata link e.g. https://analytics.dev.azure.com/companyName/myProjectName/_odata/v4.0-preview/$metadata

Comment: Post the error as *text*, not an image. The image that shows how you defined the field doesn't really help. What does the metadata show? Does that type have the fields you expected?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, the custom field defined is matters because that is the first point to understand how do you create a custom field on azure. The metadata shows all field that exists on azure along with custom fields, metadata is in XML format so it will help to understand the complete hierarchy of properties or fields and the way of access to them. I expect metadata should contain my custom Custom_TestingType field. In my, Odata query I was already able to access the custom_Module field.

Comment: I know about OData and its `$metadata` endpoint. It's not Azure-specific. I use it for my Blazor WASM applications. That's why I say the screenshots don't really matter, but the `$metadata` contents *do*. Post the metadata XML. The error says the field isn't there. Is it? If not, this is an Azure bug and I doubt anyone at SO could help you. It's fare more likely that the field isn't named the way you think though. Or perhaps it's defined on a different type. The screenshot doesn't show *anything* beyond the field name. Unless `Test Case` is a type, in which case your query is wrong

Comment: Your query tries to filter  `WorkItemSnapshot` items by `WorkItemType =  'Test Case'` and then group them by the `WorkItemSnapshot.Custom_TestingType` field. Without the metadata one can only guess, but I'd guess this screenshot shows defining a `Testing_Type` on a `Test_Case` type. That's why you need to post the `$metadata`, so people can actually see what the schema is

Comment: Thanks for posting the metadata link.  That was a huge help!

Comment: @LawMan, Your welcome. Meta data indeed useful to get complete picture of azure schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue resolved automatically. Newly created Custom filed on azure may takes time at least 1-2 days to reflect in metadata schema. New field appear immediately on azure filter query but access through oData query using power BI takes time.